# Implementing SelectableDataModel

Tags: jsf, primefaces

XHTML side:

```
<p:dataTable id="selectProductTable" var="product"  value="#{manageFormsView.productModel}" selection="#{manageFormsView.product}" >
```

bean side:

```
  private SelectableDataModel<Product>  productModel=new SelectableDataModel<Product>() {


                @Override  
                public Product getRowData(String rowKey) {  
                    //In a real app, a more efficient way like a query by rowKey should be implemented to deal with huge data  


                    for(Product product : productList) {  
                        if(product.getModel().equals(rowKey))  
                            return product;  
                    }  

                    return null;  
                }  

                @Override  
                public Object getRowKey(Product p) {  
                    return p.getModel();  
                }  
        };
```

i do not want to generate a new class which implements SDM, can not i do inline implementaton like above?

I am getting exception:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The exception message is misleading. Implementing only the `SelectableDataModel` interface is not sufficient. You also need to **extend** an [`DataModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html) implementation such as `ListDataModel`. That can't be done in flavor of an anonymous class. You really need to create another class.

```
public class ProductDataModel extends ListDataModel<Product> implements SelectableDataModel<Product> {

    // ...

}
```

You can if necessary generify it if you have a common base entitiy (with `getId()` and so on), so that you don't need to create another one for every entity.

```
public class BaseEntityDataModel<E extends BaseEntity> extends ListDataModel<E> implements SelectableDataModel<E> {

    // ...

}
```

As a completely different alternative, you can also use `rowKey` attribtue of the `<p:dataTable>` and let it refer exactly the same value as `SelectableDataModel#getRowKey()`. This way you don't need the whole `SelectableDataModel` interface anymore.

```
<p:dataTable ... rowKey="#{product.model}">
```

#### See also:

- [PrimeFaces showcase example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml)

Answer (score 6):

Since you don't seem to have any special function for `getRowData` and `getRowKey`, I think you don't need to do such complicated things. `<p:dataTable>` has the single selection mode with `selection` and `rowKey` attributes which should do the job sufficiently. Your table should be something like this:

```
<p:dataTable var="p" value="#{mrBean.products}" rowKey="#{p.model}"
             selection="#{mrBean.selectedProduct}"  selectionMode="single">
   ... // Your columns
</p:dataTable>
```

And you can get the selected row in the `selectedProduct` property of your `ManagedBean` as following:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MrBean {
   private List<Product> products;
   private Product       selectedProduct;

   // Getters and Setters
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. i tried before without rowKey, it gives error that p:dataTable need SelectableDataModel. i generate a new class and implement SDM and it is working now, but i am going to try your solution also it seems elegant.

Comment: @tuxi I think my code should be sufficient. You don't need to implement the `productModel` at all :).