# PrimeFaces blank LazyDataModel after many views

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, lazy-evaluation, selectable

Everything works fine, but after strong number of views, the jsf that has my lazyDataTable becomes blank and the error was printed on log:

```
DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled.
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getRowKeyFromModel(DataTable.java:965)
```

I searched many times a solution but, but everything told, I just implemented. And ONLY after strong number of views, the problem described occurs.

My class of lazy data table has:

```
public class MyClass extends LazyDataModel<T> implements SelectableDataModel<T>
```

and the override methods:

```
getRowKey
getRowData
```

I just try put the rowKey on p:dataTable

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: I think [this][1] explain how work **selectableDataModel**


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834244/implementing-selectabledatamodel